# Base64 decode to a Hex dump

Tags: java, base64, hex

I've a base64 string like this.

```
RALCgjQwMDA5wrNJb1QNAGNvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEHZGVmYXVsdBEyIBRydD0yITLDncOiBElvVC9jb2FwX25vc2VjXzAxHQMxMjM0NS0wMDc3Nzg5Nzk5bShjb2FwOi8vMTkyLjE2OC4yNTAuMTE6MTU2ODUvSW9UL2NvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEvZGVmYXVsdEEEw797Im0ybTpjaW4iOnsiY29uIjoiRXhhbXBsZUNJTiJ9fQ==
```

I'd like to convert this into hex dump as below,

```
4402823430303039b3496f540d00636f61705f6e6f7365635f30310764656661756c741132201472743d322132dde204496f542f636f61705f6e6f7365635f30311d0331323334352d303037373738393739396d28636f61703a2f2f3139322e3136382e3235302e31313a31353638352f496f542f636f61705f6e6f7365635f30312f64656661756c744104ff7b226d326d3a63696e223a7b22636f6e223a224578616d706c6543494e227d7d
```

This conversion was done [using this online tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-hex-bin-dec-converter.html).

I'm trying to achieve the same with this Java code,

```
String base64 = "RALCgjQwMDA5wrNJb1QNAGNvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEHZGVmYXVsdBEyIBRydD0yITLDncOiBElvVC9jb2FwX25vc2VjXzAxHQMxMjM0NS0wMDc3Nzg5Nzk5bShjb2FwOi8vMTkyLjE2OC4yNTAuMTE6MTU2ODUvSW9UL2NvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEvZGVmYXVsdEEEw797Im0ybTpjaW4iOnsiY29uIjoiRXhhbXBsZUNJTiJ9fQ==";
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
String hexDump = String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, bytes));
```

But the result is different. Any clues whats wrong in the code?

```
4402c2823430303039c2b3496f540d00636f61705f6e6f7365635f30310764656661756c741132201472743d322132c39dc3a204496f542f636f61705f6e6f7365635f30311d0331323334352d303037373738393739396d28636f61703a2f2f3139322e3136382e3235302e31313a31353638352f496f542f636f61705f6e6f7365635f30312f64656661756c744104c3bf7b226d326d3a63696e223a7b22636f6e223a224578616d706c6543494e227d7d
```

Comment: Don't try to convert to a `BigInteger`. Just convert each individual byte into hex.

Comment: I don't know how you used that site to convert that Base64 text to that Hex string, but it appears to be flawed. Testing on multiple other sites, they all give same result as Java, e.g. https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex, http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en, https://conv.darkbyte.ru/, ... Try more sites from web search of [`base64 to hex`](https://www.google.com/search?q=base64+to+hex)

Comment: to be precise: you actually want a hexdump of the decoded base64 string.

Comment: To me looks like the rapidTables site you are using is broken, Your answer looks correct. I would delete this question!

Comment: Thank you all. The tool was wrong. This tool produced the correct encode https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String base64 = "RALCgjQwMDA5wrNJb1QNAGNvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEHZGVmYXVsdBEyIBRydD0yITLDncOiBElvVC9jb2FwX25vc2VjXzAxHQMxMjM0NS0wMDc3Nzg5Nzk5bShjb2FwOi8vMTkyLjE2OC4yNTAuMTE6MTU2ODUvSW9UL2NvYXBfbm9zZWNfMDEvZGVmYXVsdEEEw797Im0ybTpjaW4iOnsiY29uIjoiRXhhbXBsZUNJTiJ9fQ==";

byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);

StringBuilder sbHexDump = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : bytes){
        sbHexDump.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
System.out.println(sbHexDump.toString());
```

The format specifier is what matters here:
"%02x" will make 4402c2 (the second byte is 2, due to format it will produce 02). Not needed when using BigInteger but I would prefer my solution ;)